# Alternative for Options MultiViews on new Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, pretty-urls

i am using in htaccess

```
AcceptpathInfo On
Options MultiViews
MultiviewsMatch Handlers
```

to set pretty URL and something more. This set extension in filename as optional. For examle http://server.com/index will be the same as http://server.com/index.php (more useful it is in robots.txt.php, style.css.php and more). But after update to new version of XAMPP (Apache 2.4.10 and PHP 5.6.3) it doesn´t work (error 403), but in older XAMPP it works. Do you know about any alternative for this or how to set it? Error is at line

```
Options MultiViews
```

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with Multiviews?

Comment: Yes, it's used in book (CZ; 1001 tipů a triků pro PHP; Jakub Vrána; 2012) and i used it in many web projects and it everytime works.

Comment: So if you remove the Multiviews option you no longer get a 403?

Comment: Yes, when i remove `Options MultiViews` it return 200 but request without file extension does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, noticed something that may address your problem. So, with apache 2.4, you *need* a `+` or `-` in front of each option, so you need:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

If that still doesn't work, maybe mod_rewrite can do it (but you need to try each extension). Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check for PHP extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# chek for HTML extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

etc. for each extension you want to check for.